# Cron + nohup = script in cron cannot find command?

Tags: bash, cron, nohup

There is a simple cron job:

```
@reboot /home/user/scripts/run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**run.sh** starts a binary (simple web server):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
NPID=/home/user/server/websrv

if [ ! -f $NPID ]
    then
        echo "Not started"
        echo "Starting"
        nohup home/user/server/websrv &> my_script.out &
    else
        NUM=$(ps ax | grep $(cat $NPID) | grep -v grep | wc -l)
        if [ $NUM -lt 1 ]
        then
            echo "Not working"
            echo "Starting"
            nohup home/user/server/websrv &> my_script.out &
        else
            ps ax | grep $(cat $NPID) | grep -v grep
            echo "All Ok"
        fi
fi
```

**websrv** gets JSON from user, and runs **work.sh** script itselves.

The problem is that **sh script**, which is invoked by **websrv**, "does not see" commands and stops with exit 1.

The script **work.sh** is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 INPUT"
    exit 1
fi

cd $(dirname $0) #good!
pwd #good!

IN="$1"
echo $IN #good!
KEYFORGIT="/some/path"
eval `ssh-agent -s` #good!
which ssh-add #good! (returns /usr/bin/ssh-add)
ssh-add $KEYFORGIT/openssh #error: exit 1!

git pull #error: exit 1!

cd $(dirname $0) #good!

rm -f somefile #error: exit 1!

#############==========Etc.==============
```

Usage of the full paths does not help.
If the script has been executed itself, it works.
If **run.sh** manually, it also works.
If I run the command nohup home/user/server/websrv & if works as well.
However, if all this chain of tools is started by cron on boot, **work.sh** is not able to perform any command except of cp, pwd, which, etc. But invoke of ssh-add, git, cp, rm, make etc., forces exit 1 status of the script. Why it "does not see" the commands? Unfortunately, I also cannot get any extended log which might explain the particular errors.

Comment: First: when troubleshooting a cron job, *do not* use `> /dev/null 2>&1` -- that hides what's going on as the script runs, but you need to know what's happening. Replace it with something like `>>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1`, then check that log file to see what it says. Second, cron jobs don't have the same `PATH` your normal shell does, and it probably doesn't contain the directories that `ssh-add`, `git`, etc are in. Either set the PATH in your crontab, or in the script, or use full paths to the command files. Third, `home/user/server/websrv` is not a full path, it should probably start with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path from the session that runs the script correctly to the cron entry (or inside the script)

Get the current path (where the script runs fine) with `echo $PATH` and add that to the crontab: replacing the string below with the output -> `<REPLACE_WITH_OUTPUT_FROM_ABOVE>`

```bash
@reboot export PATH=$PATH:<REPLACE_WITH_OUTPUT_FROM_ABOVE>; /home/user/scripts/run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can compare paths with a cron entry like this to see what cron's PATH is:

```bash
* * * * * echo $PATH > /tmp/crons_path
```

Then `cat /tmp/crons_path` to see what it says.

Example output:

```bash
$ crontab -l | grep -v \#
* * * * * echo $PATH >> /tmp/crons_path

# wait a minute or so...
$ cat /tmp/crons_path
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

As the commenter above mentioned, crontab doesn't always use the same path as user so likely something is missing.

Be sure to remove the temp cron entry after testing (`crontab -e`, etc.)...